# Randomizing/Modifing Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, random

So I'm trying to randomize an array of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. Then ask for the user to select a position in the array, and modify it. After that, it should display the number the user entered for **all** of the 10 values. Finally, it will need to get the original array that was randomized and reverse it.

So far, I have this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int array [10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int rarray [10];

int main() {
    cout << "Random Array = ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int index = rand() % 10;

        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[index];
        array[index] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        cout << array[i] << " "; //somehow, this display needs to be entered into another array
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

But as stated in the comment, I'm stuck on as how to do this.

Comment: Arrays in C++ use zero based indexes, not one based indexes. [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) and [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) are your friends.

Comment: Please narrow down the question to the specific part of the problem that you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), and [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) from the C++ Standard Library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int position;

    // Get the position to modify and make sure it's within our bounds.
    do
    {
        cout << "Select a position: ";
    }
    while (!(cin >> position) || position < 0 || position > 9);

    int array[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int rarray[10];

    //  Shuffle the array. We use std::begin and std::end to get the bounds of
    //  of the array instead of guessing it's size.
    std::random_shuffle(std::begin(array), std::end(array));

    //  Copy it to the new array
    std::copy(std::begin(array), std::end(array), rarray);

    //  Modify the new array and display it. Add your own code here to get the
    //  value it is modified with.
    rarray[position] = 100;

    for (auto value : rarray)
        cout << value << " ";
    cout << endl;

    //  Reverse the original array and display it
    std::reverse(std::begin(array), std::end(array));

    for (auto value : array)
        cout << value << " ";
    cout << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

or if you are not allowed to use the C++ Standard Library you will need to handle everything manually. This is a tedious task but a great example of why the C++ Standard Library should be leveraged whenever possible. This is also more prone to errors, more difficult to maintain, and ugly to look at.

```
int main()
{
    int position;

    do
    {
        cout << "Select a position: ";
    } while (!(cin >> position) || position < 0 || position > 9);

    int array[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int index = rand() % 10;

        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[index];
        array[index] = temp;
    }

    //  Copy the array
    int rarray[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        rarray[i] = array[i];
    }

    //  Modify the new array and display it
    rarray[position] = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << rarray[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    //  Reverse the old array and display it
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 / 2; i++)
    {
        int tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[9 - i];
        array[9 - i] = tmp;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Both implementations are close to your original request but you may need to expand on it a little to match your requirements exactly. They should get you moving along nicely though.

Comment: If I wanted to shuffle for production code, I'd recommend a better pseudo-random number generator than rand(). I'd also recommend using STL, or borrowing code from STL if STL insists on using rand().

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. PS, the second code block is missing `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` :P